# How to generate meaningful list names in JAX-WS web services

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a schema with something along the lines of

```
<xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

and it is referenced in my wsdl. When I use wsimport to create java code, the class gets a field called

```
List<Item> item;
```

Is there a way to get it to name the field something more standard like `items` or `itemList`?

I don't want to name the `xs:element` Items because then I would get a class called `Items` which is as bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this seemed to solve it:

Instead of

```
<xs:element ref="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

I used

```
<xs:complexType name="Item">...</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ItemList" type="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

which resulted in the code:

```
List<Item> itemList;
```

Comment: Using the `name` attribute is the way to go.

Comment: +1 didn't know what was the corresponding XSD of `@WebParam(name="Item") List itemList`

Comment: Alternatively it turns out this can be done in bindings.xml. If anyone is interested, I can post that method as well.

Comment: This is very nice Java-side, but doesn't it produce an XML containing multiple <ItemList /><ItemList /><ItemList /> ? I'm still trying to have the best of both.

Comment: I think the bindings.xml method will give you `<item/><item/><item/>` in xml and `items` in java.